# Writing a custom layer in tensorflow: can't find op_def_builder.h no such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have `tensorflow` installed via `pip` and when I try writing a custom layer in `cpp`, I can't find the .h files needed. For example 
`tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h` I did some research and concluded that I need to clone the github code and build the library to generate that file. Is this true? If this is the only way, why does `tensorflow` [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) suggest that I could do this by installing the `tensorflow` binary OR building the library from the source code?

Note: `tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h` is needed by `#include tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h` which is included by `#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"` which I can find among their code posted on `github`

Comment: Can you try: https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op ?

Comment: I don't have time for this now; thank u for the comment though